# Is it possible to run a javascript for one specific site I visit using Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

This is the problem: I use iTunes Connect from Apple a lot.

Their HTML has this line

```
<input id="pwd" type="password" aria-required="true" required="required" can-field="password" autocomplete="off" class="si-password si-text-field  " placeholder="Password">
```

`autocomplete="off"` that prevents safari from filling the password field, what is annoying.

I am at home. I am the only one that uses this computer. I don't want to type the password every time.

Is that possible to make Safari run a javascript code every time I visit this site to replace autocomplete with ON before Safari renders the page?

What javascript would be and/or how do I do that?

Comment: You can build a Safari extension to inject javascript code on that webpage.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/InjectingScripts/InjectingScripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in the general case. Basically you're looking for GreaseMonkey for Safari. There seem to be several alternatives, including [GreaseKit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/). Genereally, GreaseMonkey-like tools have options for when the script should be run. I haven't used GreaseKit so I can't say for certain that it's possible to run a script early enough that the auto-fill occurs, but perhaps it does. If not, you could have it fill in the password for you, but then the password would have to be in the script and thus written (probably as cleartext) in a file on your computer.

In the normal case I'd flag up the option of using a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet): After going to the page, you trigger a bookmark for a `javascript:...` pseudo-URL that's actually code to find and remove that attribute. But unless I miss my guess, that wouldn't be in time for the autofill to fire. Of course, again, you could have it fill in the password instead, but then (again) the password would be cleartext (or easily un-obfuscated text at the very least) in the bookmark.

Example bookmarklet:

```html
<p>If you click the following link, it will show you the number of direct children <code>document.body</code> has in the current document. In this snippet (with the current version of Stack Snippets), that'll be 7. But if you right-click it, copy the link, and the paste that as the URL in a bookmark, then clicking that bookmark when you're on any page will show you how many direct children <code>document.body</code> has on <em>that page</em>, because bookmarklets execute in the page that's showing when you activate the bookmark they're part of. That's how a bookmarklet works.</p>
<a href="javascript:alert('Number of doc body children: ' + document.body.childNodes.length);">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Apparently Safari does not allow bookmarks to be made with JavaScript but I will try GreaseKit. Thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @SpaceDog: Safari doesn't let you *create* bookmarks with JavaScript, but it supports bookmarklets (bookmarks *you* create that use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol).

Comment: @SpaceDog: Code example of what? I've added a same bookmarklet above if that's what you mean.